# Run Gitlab Pipeline service with config file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to start a [Gitlab service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) alongside my "main" process.

This service requires a configuration file:

```
./myService --config=config.yaml
```

The config file in turn is not static. I need to `sed` it to include some data (to which I have access at runtime).

**secure.json**

```
{
  "url": "https://example.com",
  "token": "mytoken"
}
```

**config.yaml**

```
some:
  config:
    url: https://placeholder.com
    token: tempTokenValue
```

So here's what I'm trying:

1. Store `secure.json` in [a secure file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secure_files/)
2. Read `secure.json` and get values with `jq`
3. Use `sed` to replace placeholder values in `config.yaml` with correct details
4. Use the now-valid config.yaml to start my process
5. Define that as a `service` which my "main" process can interact with

I'm trying to do all this with the "main" pipeline running in a docker container.

Is this possible? Am I even going about this the correct way? I'm happy to be told to do it a different way!